# API returns not found but the endpoint is correct

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework Endpoint

```
urlpatterns_usersettings = [
    path("usersettings/<int:pk>/", UpdateUserSettings.as_view())
]
```

and a view to deal with that endpoint:

```
class UpdateUserSettings(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserSettingsSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return UserSettings.objects.all().filter(user=user)
```

Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class UserSettings(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_settings")
    # ACCOUNT SETTINGS
    gotodash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    loginalert = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # DISPLAY SETTINGS
    darkmode = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    button_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    link_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    heading_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    title_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    tab_color = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "user settings"
        verbose_name_plural = "users settings"
        db_table = "users_settings"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s settings"
```

and here is the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UserSettings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class UserSettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserSettings
        fields = "__all__"
```

If I call the endpoint I get a 404 error and in the response it says detail not found, but if I do a breakpoint and manually get the object then it works fine I can get the object, so why can the view not get the object and update it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises from the overridden `get_queryset` method, where UserSettings objects are filtered using the `user` kwarg (`user_settings = UserSettings.objects.all().filter(user=user)`). Subsequently, the view attempts to locate the object for updating within this pre-filtered set using the `pk` passed in the URL (`user_settings.objects.get(pk=user)`), leading to a 404 error.

A recommended solution is to utilise the `get_object` method to directly retrieve the object based on the user_id:

```py
class UpdateUserSettings(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserSettingsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
        try:
            return UserSettings.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
        except UserSettings.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "User settings not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_settings = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(user_settings, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Upon issuing a PUT request to the endpoint, including the desired user in the request body, the associated UserSettings object will be updated. Using the `requests` library as an example:

```py
import requests

URL = “your_api_endpoint_here_with_the_old_user_id_as_pk"
response = requests.put(URL, json={"user": "new_user_id"})
```

Comment: Doesn't work is telling me the user field is required

Comment: What about your put method? I updated my answer and added an example of the put method.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think pk is in self.kwargs. Try accessing it directly

```
class UpdateUserSettings(generics.UpdateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = UserSettingsSerializer
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.pk
    return UserSettings.objects.all().filter(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the urls properly?

In your code, it seems you've added your view in `urlpatterns_usersettings` variable. Is it added in `urlpatterns`?

Django uses the [urlpatterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#example) to get all urls.